# Porque meu programa não gera CSV em UTF-8 que possa ser lido corretamente pelo Excel, mas o notepad gera

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, utf-8

Eu tenho gerado arquivos `.CSV` em `javascript`, em UTF-8, porém que não são lidos com a codificação correta no Microsoft Excel (gerando caracteres inválidos no lugar dos acentuados, como se tivesse lendo ISO 8859-1 ou algo assim).

A maioria dos concorrentes (Google Docs, LibreOffice, etc) abrem uma janela em que é possível escolher a codificação correta. E então eu cheguei a um `workaround` com uma resposta do stackoverflow em inglês que linkava outro forum (http://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/400043-csv-and-unicode-or-utf-8-problem.html)

Simplesmente (de acordo com esta solução, que funcionou pra mim) ao salvar como UTF-8 dentro do bloco de notas do windows (notepad), o Excel magicamente reconhece a codificação correta, como se houvesse algum metadado. Há um `combobox` no notepad que permite a escolha da codificação UTF-8.

Se o notepad consegue salvar um utf8 que o Excel consegue ler, meu programa consegue também? Se não, porque salvando pelo notepad funciona?

Obs: Eu tenho gerado em UTF-8 porque tenho precisado usar `Node.js` e `Phantom.js` e estas tecnologias dão mais suporte a escrever arquivo texto em UTF-8.

Comment: Como você está gerando o csv? Já viu isso aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964035/how-to-export-javascript-array-info-to-csv-on-client-side

Comment: @PerryWerneck acho que ele vai gravar isso no servidor / Node.js

Comment: Tentou ver se a codificação da página apra o envio também está em UTF-8? Pode ter alguma página no meio do caminho esteja com codificação ANSI... Se não resolver, vc pode ao invés de salvar o arquivo em CSV, transformá-lo em uma tabela HTML como se fosse uma página e em seguida salvá-la com a extensão XLS. Assim o excel deverá abrir sem problemas

Answer (score 3):

Tente iniciar seu arquivo com \ufeff.

Essa é a marca [BOM (Binary Byte Order)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) do UTF-8.

Comment: Funcionou para mim